# October CMS - separating content from themes

Tags: php, laravel-5, octobercms

October stores the content of your pages within the theme folders. This means that by switching themes, I'm also switching content for my website.

Other CMS's I've used such as WordPress retain the content completely separate from the themes, so I can switch themes and retain the same content and pages for the site without rebuilding or manually duplicating the pages.

How can I do this within October so that my content is separate from the theme? I've noticed that the blog plugin stores the content in the database and so that data is separate and portable. Would modifying the blog and replacing the CMS functionality with this be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I create a new plugin (with Builder Plugin) with my custom logic, database tables, models, which wrapped in custom components.
And then I insert component to standart october pages (static pages)

Comment: so, that would mean to create a new page, I would have to create the new page from the CMS backend, add a new component to reference the page content from the database, and then edit that content via a separate plugin. That's the opposite of user friendly

Comment: component are standard way to place dynamic data. You use file based pages or you use db based plugin. There is no third.